# Immediate playback with Flutter's video_player

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I have a CDN that serves videos to my Flutter application. The videos are around 20-30MB. Is there a way to instead of downloading the entire video before playing it, download the video in pieces, and immediately output the first piece to the user?

Just like http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4, doesn't download the 300MB video if you play it in the browser, but dowloads it in portions?

I tried different video players (video_player, cached_video_play, better_player...) and tried experimenting with different request headers for the CDN. Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You also have `https://server.com/files/video.mp4` MP4 video file link?
Make sure it's a `faststart` or `fragmentedMp4` file.

I did not try this but maybe this is enough to make it a `faststart (MOOV header copied to the start of file)` without transcoding. If you need to transcode you can give same flags along with the usual codec+bitrate attributes.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a copy -movflags "negative_cts_offsets+faststart" -y video_new.mp4
```

MOOV tells the details of stream (codec, resolution, etc..) and should be found at the start of file, but it may be found at the end if file was for a disk storage use.

Fragmented mp4 is a technique interleaving payloads for streaming but may introduce problems for forward/rewind without the HLS-DASH manifest descriptor files. Very old players don't support fragmented mp4 file.

If you want to transcode you may try this one.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -preset fast -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level 4.0 \
  -s:v 640x360 -b:v 712k -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -refs 3 -bf 3 -g 50 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -flags +cgop -sc_threshold 0 \
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -maxrate:a 128k -bufsize:a 128k -af aresample=48000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 \
  -movflags "negative_cts_offsets+faststart" \
  -y video_new.mp4
```